# Почему не хочет запускаться, если есть ссылка на сторонний проект?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xunit

Делаю отдельный проект с тестированием, но когда пытаюсь запустить, получаю ошибку:

> *Tests/ControllersTests/ArticlesControllerTests.cs(26,26): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ArticlesController' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) (Tests)

Ссылку добавил, и vs не ругается на эти классы. Вот сам класс:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Moq;
using TrainingTests.Controllers;
using TrainingTests.Repository;
using Xunit;

namespace Tests.ControllersTests
{
    public class ArticlesControllerTests: IDisposable
    {
        private readonly ArticlesController articles;

        public ArticlesControllerTests()
        {
            var dbContextMock = new Mock<MySqlContext>();
            var loggerMock = new Mock<ILogger<ArticlesController>>();

            articles = new ArticlesController(loggerMock.Object, dbContextMock.Object);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void GetAllArticles()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Example");
            //Assert.Equal(articles.GetAll().Value.Count, 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну, если ссылка действительно добавлена... В [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0246) в одном из пунктов сказано, что версии платформ сборок могут не совпадать.

Comment: В обоих стоит 3.1 версия

Comment: Есть какие-то подвижки? Мне интересно, в чём проблема.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Создал новый проект, и все сразу стало нормально!

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Можете дать ссылку на пример moq? то я делаю как в metanit, но у меня не получается(

Например сейчас в контроллере не могу получить список выдает ошибку: не правильного типа объект